# MS SQL Not recording all transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I use a Sql Server database to record logs of my game. Every move gets recorded to a specific table. I'm using a stored procedure to record the logs, around 50k logs per day.

Recently I noticed it doesn't record all of the logs that are submitted. Some days I only have 2000 logs and some days I have 100,000. I can't find anything wrong with my code to cause this.

How many calls of a stored procedure can be done in a second?
What could be the reason for dropping so many calls?
What can i do to make sure all the calls are being inserted to the Table?
Would it help to use normal calls and not stored procedure calls?

Comment: You shoud add error handling to your sp. If you have identity field in your table check it for gaps, if there are gaps your transactions were rolled back

Comment: SQL Server doesn't drop calls. If records are missing it means your stored procedure failed. Whatever called it should have logged the failure. How is this stored procedure called? Or it could be that the queries just didn't return the amount of records you expectd. Without at least the source code of the stored procedure it's impossible to help.

Comment: `I can't find anything wrong with my code to cause this.` do you use `catch{}` anywhere? Do you log exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

> How many calls of a stored procedure can be done in a second?

Immaterial.  Your DBMS is not "losing" transactions due to being overwhelmed.

> What could be the reason for dropping so many calls?

What evidence do you have that even one call is being dropped?  You didn't mention any.

> What can i do to make sure all the calls are being inserted to the Table?

Look for places where your transaction isn't being committed.

> Would it help to use normal calls and not stored procedure calls?

No, the opposite.  Stored procedures are more efficient, and give you security features not otherwise available.

My guess is you're not committing your updates.  Either you're failing to call *commit* every time, or you're failing to notice an error that prevents the update from being applied.

The first thing I'd check is the connection property that controls whether **COMMIT** is implicit or explicit.  If you set the connection *not* to require an explicit commit from the application, then every **INSERT** is committed atomically.  That seems like what you'd want for a log table.

What you might do is create a "log log table", and insert into it every time you call your stored procedure, and again every time it finishes, with time and status.  Make absolutely sure updates to the log table are not part of some larger transaction that might get rolled back.  Verify that by checking `@@trancount`.  Return an error if it's greater than 1, and make sure you're recording errors correctly.  If you include key information in your log table, you can compare it to the main table to see who's missing what.  I bet it will reveal clues.

In your application you might similarly write to a log file every time you update the server, and every time it answers, and record time and status.  If that log disagrees with your log table, you know you have something to look into.

You're right about one thing: if the updates are arriving over a network, there's a chance the connection is being dropped.  If it's dropped before the commit, that would explain the lost updates, because the insertion is rolled back.

Comment: If there was an autoincrement column, would it show gaps for rollbacks?

Comment: @CaiusJard, if the insert succeeded and the transaction later rolled back, there will be gaps.